# How to run Python script batch file with installed modules

Tags: python, selenium, batch-file, triggers

I am trying to set up a batch file for a python script to run at a certain time every day. I set it up as such:

```
"C:\Users\payto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" "C:\Users\payto\OneDrive\Documents\MIPS_Platform\script.py" pause
```

Problem is, when the script is called from the batch file I receive an error saying that :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Selenium is installed in the folder but is not recognized when called from the batch file. How do I get around this?

Comment: Selenium is installed in which folder? As you've stated that the script is being run at a specific time of day, I'm going to assume that you're running it as a scheduled task. Depending upon the user under which you're running it, you probably need to change things to run with a specific directory as current. You should be able to do that by either setting it in the task scheduler via `Start in (optional)` or by simply adding the following line to the very top of your batch file, `@CD /D "%~dp0"` for the scripts directory, or `@CD /D "S:\ome\Location"` if different.

Comment: Selenium is installed in the same folder as the script. I can call it from the terminal in that folder but the batch file call does not recognize it is installed. I tried setting the "Start in" spot to that folder but still no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: What about adding the simple line, `@CD /D "%~dp0"`, to the top of your script, as I also stated?

Comment: You should also note that ` pause` at the end is not valid if you meant to pause the batch script execution. As it stands you're sending `pause` as an argument to your python command, did you mean to use ` & pause` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add 'C:\Users\payto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe` to the system environment variable and then try the below

```
cmd /k python "C:\Users\payto\OneDrive\Documents\MIPS_Platform\script.py"
```

This will make sure the cmd window does not close after running the script.py